# JFreeChart: ChartMouseClicked not working

Tags: jfreechart, mouseclick-event

I'm using the JFreeChart library and created a `chartPanel` with `chartMouseListener`. What is strange is that the `chartPanel` did respond to `chartMouseMove` event but the `chartMouseClicked` is never trigger even though I've clicked very hard.

Any one can throw some light upon this issue? Really appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With out seeing your, code it is quite hard to guess what it going on.  You must implement `ChartMouseListener` somewhere and then add it to the chart panel.

```
public class MyChart implements ChartMouseListener
```

later

```
chartPanel.addChartMouseListener(this)
```

then override the the chartMouseClicked method

```
@Override
public void chartMouseClicked(ChartMouseEvent e){
    if(e.getTrigger().getButton() ==  MouseEvent.BUTTON1) {
        //do something interesting
    }
}
```